# access denied to create database vps cpanel mysql

Tags: mysql, permissions

im running mysql on a godaddy vps. Its a fresh build. Mysql version 8.0.31.

i got into terminal as root and created a user. I granted that user all privileges on *.*  with grant option.

When i show grants i see this user has all privileges with grant on *.*.

when i login as this user either on terminal or remotely through dbforge, when i create a database i get the error access denied for the user.

Ive done this in the past but it has been a while since i spun up a new mysql server. Last time i did it was on mysql 5.7, i think.

I still have 5.7 running and i can create databases no problem.

Anyone run into something like this? Btw, if i create the database from the terminal as root. I can manipulate with my user and even drop the database. Once created my user can grant rights as well. Somehow the CREATE Privilege is not working even though it is listed when i show grants.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO ...`  (Did you say "*.*"?

Comment: this was the statement i ran.  Like i said the user can do anything but create a database. 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%';